# Error Compiling GDAL with ESRI FileGeodatabase Support On Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gdal, file-geodatabase, ogr, ubuntu

I am attempting to build GDAL in Docker/Ubuntu 16.04 for use in Postgis2.2/[OGR_FDW](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-ogr-fdw) on Postgres 9.6 beta3 using the [travis.yml](https://github.com/rouault/gdal_coverage/blob/2.1_gcc5.2_sanitize/.travis.yml) of the 2.1_gcc5.2_sanitize coverage branch as a guide -as there is oddly no coverage for the current Ubuntu LTS.

My requirements include using the ESRI FGDB driver to enable write support -as FileGeodabases are becoming almost as prolific as shapefiles. Thus, it would be unfortunate to go through all the effort of building the Swiss Army Knife of the GIS world without support for writing the 2nd most common vector format (that I encounter anyway).

However, during GDAL `make`, I received the following soul-destroying error when attempting to compile using the standard build-essential package:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/FileGDBAPI.h:28:0,
                 from filegdbsdk_headers.h:39,
                 from ogr_fgdb.h:50,
                 from FGdbDatasource.cpp:33:
/usr/local/include/GeodatabaseManagement.h:56:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 EXT_FILEGDB_API fgdbError CreateGeodatabase(const std::wstring& path, Geodatabase& geodatabase);
 ^
/usr/local/include/GeodatabaseManagement.h:64:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 EXT_FILEGDB_API fgdbError OpenGeodatabase(const std::wstring& path, Geodatabase& geodatabase);
 ^
/usr/local/include/GeodatabaseManagement.h:69:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 EXT_FILEGDB_API fgdbError CloseGeodatabase(Geodatabase& geodatabase);
 ^
/usr/local/include/GeodatabaseManagement.h:77:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 EXT_FILEGDB_API fgdbError DeleteGeodatabase(const std::wstring& path);
 ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/FileGDBAPI.h:29:0,
                 from filegdbsdk_headers.h:39,
                 from ogr_fgdb.h:50,
                 from FGdbDatasource.cpp:33:
/usr/local/include/Geodatabase.h:60:23: error: expected initializer before 'Geodatabase'
 class EXT_FILEGDB_API Geodatabase
                       ^
FGdbDatasource.cpp:760:1: error: expected '}' at end of input
 }
 ^
make[3]: *** [../o/FGdbDatasource.lo] Error 1
```

**What steps do I need to take to get the driver to compile correctly without breaking any other drivers?**

Build commands below:

```
set -e

FGDB_DIR=FileGDB_API-64
FGDB_DOWNLOAD=FileGDB_API_1_4-64.tar.gz
apt-get update
apt-get install -y gcc-4.8 g++-4.8 subversion wget zip git scons ant \
  build-essential software-properties-common cmake python-pip

wget -q -O /tmp/${FGDB_DOWNLOAD} https://github.com/Esri/file-geodatabase-api/raw/master/FileGDB_API_1_4-64.tar.gz
tar -C /tmp -xzf /tmp/${FGDB_DOWNLOAD} && ls /tmp
cd /tmp/${FGDB_DIR}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`/lib
cd samples
make CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.8 CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.8
cp ../lib/* /usr/local/lib
cp ../include/* /usr/local/include
ldconfig
rm -rf ${FGDB_DOWNLOAD} ${FGDB_DIR}

svn checkout --quiet "http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/branches/2.1/gdal" /tmp/gdal/
cd /tmp/gdal
add-apt-repository -y -u ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
apt-get install -y \
  python-numpy \
  python-dev \
  libpng12-dev \
  libjpeg-dev \
  libgif-dev \
  liblzma-dev \
  libgeos-dev \
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
  libproj-dev \
  libxml2-dev \
  libexpat-dev \
  libxerces-c-dev \
  libnetcdf-dev \
  netcdf-bin \
  libpoppler-dev \
  libspatialite-dev \
  gpsbabel \
  swig \
  libhdf4-alt-dev \
  libpodofo-dev \
  poppler-utils \
  libfreexl-dev \
  unixodbc-dev \
  libwebp-dev \
  libepsilon-dev \
  liblcms2-2 \
  libpcre3-dev
./configure CXX="g++ -std=c++14" CPPFLAGS="-DMAKE_SANITIZE_HAPPY -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address" LDFLAGS="-fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address" \
    --prefix=/usr/local \
    --with-jpeg12 \
    --with-python \
    --with-poppler \
    --with-podofo \
    --with-spatialite \
    --with-mysql \
    --with-liblzma \
    --with-webp \
    --with-java=$JAVA_HOME \
    --with-mdb \
    --with-jvm-lib-add-rpath \
    --with-epsilon \
    --with-fgdb=/usr/local
make
make install
ldconfig
```